# Which of the given sentences are correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. She didn't **make** **any** effort to catch the train.
> 2. She didn't **put** **any** effort to catch the train.
> 3. She didn't **make** **an** effort to catch the train.
> 4. She didn't **put in** **any** effort to catch the train.

Which of these above sentences are correct? I have seen people use the third one and the forth one. I looked up examples sentences similar to all four of those sentences and i could find too many results for the first one. 
Is it okay to use the first one?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  It seems like OP has made at least the minimal effort to try and figure out which is correct, so I would let it slide, at least for that reason.  I'm not certain this can't be answered by a dictionary, but sometimes that's not as straightforward as it seems for English learners.

Comment: I think 1, 3, and 4 are correct, but 2 needs to use “into catching” instead of “to catch”.

Comment: @Andrew I didn't find examples of the first sentence. The third and the forth one seemed the to be the better choice to me. And, I used the first one, "make any", writing some paper, and was just wondering what I'd used was correct or not.

Comment: @SoumyaGhosh  I've used variations on the first sentence many times.  It's perfectly valid, e.g. *I really haven't **made any effort** to answer this question properly*

Comment: @Andrew Is there a difference between **haven't made any effort** and **haven't made an effort**?

Comment: meaning wise, I mean.

Comment: @SoumyaGhosh  There is no significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentences 1, 3 and 4 are fine. Sentence 2 needs "into" rather than "to", and then make "catch" > "catching." AS: She didn't put any effort into catching the train.
In comparing the written sentences, the first sentence indicates that she didn't even try to catch the train while the third sentence indicates that she may have tried, but not very hard. But in speaking these sentences, either one will work (few people pay a lot of attention to individual words!!)